# N-API pass argument within require statement

Tags: c++, node.js, node-addon-api

I am creating an n-api module, is it possible to pass an argument when the require is called?

#### js wrapper

```js
const NativeAPI = new (require('./../build/Release/mymodule.node')).Hello(3);
// how do i access this argument 3 inside TestClass::Init()
```

#### cpp wrapper

```cpp
Napi::Object InitAll(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    return TestClass::Init(env, exports);
}
NODE_API_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, InitAll);
```

#### cpp class

```cpp
Napi::FunctionReference TestClass::constructor;
Napi::Object TestClass::Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    // access 3 here
    Napi::HandleScope scope(env);
    Napi::Function func = DefineClass(env, "Hello", {
        InstanceMethod("create", &TestClass::create),
        InstanceMethod("delete", &TestClass::del)
    });
    constructor = Napi::Persistent(func);
    constructor.SuppressDestruct();
    exports.Set("Hello", func);
    return exports;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is not possible, instead create a constructor and pass any arguments to the constructor.